# How to use loadrunner for multiple URL's

Tags: loadrunner

I'm working on a Single sing on project. While recording i give URL "abc.com", the system checks the credentials and grants access to the application. Now, in the application i have to click on a button, which opens a new window with URL "xyz.com", however nothing is being recorded on Vugen. I assume it's because i gave "abc.com" while recording and it doesn't identify "xyz.com". This is my assumption. Can any one please let me know how to overcome this type of scenario?

My requirement is to logon "abc.com" using UserID/Pwd and click on a tab which opens "xyz.com" and perform actions and determine how much time does it take.

Answer (score 0):

Poor assumption.  Were this the case then no third party references would ever be noted in your recording, either as direct URL requests or as Extra Resources (EXTRARES) in HTML style requests.

Have you considered recording in Proxy mode, or even setting the global HTTP proxy (which would then be respected by all HTTP/Browser sessions) to the recording proxy for LoadRunner?

Answer (score 0):

Recording multiple URLs is a common use case for Loadrunner. I'm guessing it's something related to the fact it's opening in a new window.

I would try using a different capture level in the recording options:

```
Record -> Recording Options -> Mapping and Filtering -> Capture Level - WinINet.
```

Also try different recording types (HTML and URL based) to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Architecturally why would you suggest WinInet, as this is related to Windows Integrated Authentication?